# Sitecore Azure deployment

Tags: sitecore, azure-web-app-service, sitecore8

I want to deploy my Sitecore website to Azure. 
I am referencing https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/azure/310/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_310-a4.pdf

this pdf file to setup Sitecore Azure but dont know where to put Azure account details its all working at local, has anyone used this before or have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The doc you using is dated,
go to the new Sitecore Documentation site [install_sitecore_azure](https://doc.sitecore.net/en/cloud/azure/install_sitecore_azure)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will refer this link. From where to get Environment file?